# Is it possible to specify that Outlook should render the text version of an email?

Tags: email, outlook, html-email

I'd like to send both text and html versions of emails, but have Outlook users always only see the text version. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to target a client through MIME is impossible as far as I can tell. You can however wrap everything inside your HTML `<body>` (including your style tag if you have one) in:

```
<body>
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
    HTML CONTENT GOES HERE
<!--<![endif]-->
```

and then right before your closing `</body>` put the plain text version you want Outlook users to see inside this:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
    PLAIN TEXT GOES HERE
<![endif]-->
</body>
```